# Does Contiki-NG support Radio Duty Cycling (RDC)?

Tags: iot, contiki, contiki-ng

I'm currently developing a wireless sensor network project with Contiki-NG. However, I need to add Radio Duty Cycling feature to save energy. It was possible to add RDC in Contiki using contiki mac. It seems to be Contiki-ng does not have such thing as contiki mac. All I can see inside *contiki-ng/os/net/mac/* are CSMA MAC, BLE MAC, TSCH MAC, NullMAC and some shared MAC components. Is there any way we can use RDC on Contiki-NG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TSCH if you need duty cycling: TSCH does it on its own.

Or you can togggle CSMA on and off from the application code.