# How to make a sink mote run with 100% duty cycle in Contiki-NG where RDC no longer exists

Tags: macos, contiki, contiki-ng, radio-transmission

I'm developing a project using Contiki-NG. I need to re-create a sink kind of mote where the data sink runs with a 100% duty cycle in order to ensure high packet reception rates.
I understood from the topic [does-contiki-ng-support-radio-duty-cycling-rdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402791/does-contiki-ng-support-radio-duty-cycling-rdc) that RDC layer is gone but I don't quite catched how to work around this problem.

In the previous version of the project the code used was:

```
#define NETSTACK_CONF_RDC     nullrdc_driver
NETSTACK_RDC.off(1);
```

Any help in proceding to Contiki-NG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use CSMA as the mac protocol, it will use 100% duty cycle by default.

In application's Makefile set:

```
MAKE_MAC = MAKE_MAC_CSMA
```